# Does Awesomium allow me to call/use C++ variables/methods in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, awesomium

Awesomium easily allows for C++ code to call Javascript methods, but I haven't found a definite answer as to if it can do the opposite. [This site](http://princeofcode.com/blog/?p=285) seems to say that you can, but looking through the text and examples doesn't enlighten me.

So, I'm looking for a definite answer: can I call C++ variables/methods in my Javascript(Jquery), or not?

If you could include a simple example, that would be extremely appreciated as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You definitely can-- you'll just need to build an extra layer on top of WebView::setObjectCallback and WebViewListener::onCallback using delegates/function-pointers.

I wrote a quick JSDelegate.h class ([view it here](https://gist.github.com/906917)) that you can use to hookup "onCallback" events directly to C++ member functions.

The basic idea is to maintain a mapping of callback names to delegates:

```
typedef std::map<std::wstring, Awesomium::JSDelegate> DelegateMap;
DelegateMap _delegateMap;
```

And call the corresponding function from your WebViewListener::onCallback:

```
void MyListener::onCallback(Awesomium::WebView* caller, const std::wstring& objectName, 
    const std::wstring& callbackName, const Awesomium::JSArguments& args)
{
    DelegateMap::iterator i = _delegateMap.find(callbackName);

    if(i != _delegateMap.end())
        i->second(caller, args);
}
```

And then, each time you wish to bind a specific C++ function, you would do it like so:

```
// Member function we wish to bind, must have this signature for JSDelegate
void MyClass::myFunction(Awesomium::WebView* caller, const Awesomium::JSArguments& args)
{
    // handle args here
}

// Instantiate MyClass instance in C++
MyClass* myClass = new MyClass();

// Create corresponding 'MyClass' object in Javascript
webView->createObject(L"MyClass");

// Do the following for each member function:    
// Bind MyClass::myFunction delegate to MyClass.myFunction in JS
_delegateMap[L"myFunction"] = Awesomium::JSDelegate(myClass, &MyClass::myFunction);
webView->setObjectCallback(L"MyClass", L"myFunction");
```

Then, you should be able to call MyClass::myFunction directly from Javascript like so:

```
MyClass.myFunction("foo", 1, 2 3)
```

Hope this helps! I haven't tested any of the code but I wrote it with [Awesomium v1.6 RC4 SDK](http://www.khrona.com/products/awesomium/download) in mind.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, the above code only maps functions based on callback name-- the typedef for DelegateMap should really be std::map<std::pair<std::wstring,std::wstring>, JSDelegate> for a pair of Object Name + Callback Name.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a good answer. You put a lot of effort into it. Even if this does not end up working for me, I'll still have a better understanding of the subject.

Comment: Briz No wonder, he's on an Awesomium dev team ;) Nice answer, though. Thanks, @Adam.

Comment: adam do u know how can I call c# methods from javascript?...my knowledges in c++ are very limited and I'm using awesomiumsharp..thanks!!